# Como Atualizar um Registro no BD usando ADVPL

Tags: advpl

Estou com dificuldades para fazer uma coisa que deveria ser bem simples.

Eu criei um campo customizado para uma tabela chamado `SALDO`.

No meu código é feito um `SELECT` para acessar os registros que me interessam com um alias `TMP`. Após esse `SELECT` faço um loop desses registros e mostro para meu usuario em forma de lista de produtos. Meu usuário irá alterar alguns valores do `aCols` e baseado no que ele alterar eu devo fazer um calculo e salvar esse valor no banco no campo `SALDO` desse tal registro, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso. O que tentei e não deu certo é o seguinte:

```
DbSelectArea("TABELA")
RecLock("TMP2", .F.)
TMP2->SALDO := 400
MSUnLock()
```

Não posso postar meu código completo por política da empresa mas um esboço de como ele funciona pode ser visto abaixo:

```
_cQuery := "SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4,SALDO FROM TABELA
_cQuery := ChangeQuery(_cQuery)
TCQUERY _cQuery NEW ALIAS "TMP"
DbSelectArea("TMP")
DbGoTop()
While TMP->(!(EOF()))
//Carrega valores no aCols dentro do while


RecLock("TMP2", .F.)
TMP2->SALDO := 400
MSUnLock()
TMP->(Dbskip())
EndDo
TMP->(DbCloseArea())
```

Estou recebendo o erro  `TOP Error -19 - Invalid Operation - Update NOT ALLOWED on Query File.` quando tento fazer a atualização.

Comment: Se não pode postar então terá que se virar. Uma coisa eu já posso dizer, os exemplos da documentação são todos muito ruins. Quando eu trabalhava lá eu fazia códigos muito mais simples que estes que eles ensinam fazer. Não posso ajudar mais também porque essa coisa de SQL não é da minha época.

Comment: @bigown aliás, essa mistura de SQL com função e com ->alias vira uma bela salada. Fica parecendo uma criação do Dr. Frankenstein. Uma das coisas mais interessantes de xBase em geral é o fato de você não precisar de SQL, e parece que o pessoal anda na contramão, criando algo sem identidade. Eu abandonei as funções originals de DB faz muito tempo em favor de SQL, mas só por falta de um equivalente moderno pra Harbour (por enquanto :P ) e pela simples razão que o SQLite é muito poderoso para banco local.

Comment: @Bacco mas veja o lado bom, isso dá bastante problema e assim gera uma quantidade enorme de empregos. Eu tenho a impressão que 90% das pessoas que trabalham com AdvPL estariam desempregados ou fazendo outra coisa se fosse feito pra funcionar. Os `dbSelectArea()` existem pra fazer dar problema. O que eu acho mais curioso é a mistura deles com alias em cada membro :) Quando o fornecedor da tecnologia usa errado não tem como as coisas darem certo. Você trocou o RDD pelo SQL, não manteve os dois, aí sim.

Comment: @bigown só falta um `SET FILTER` aí pra resolver tudo /s

Comment: O erro é auto-explicativo: "TOP Error -19 - Invalid Operation - Update NOT ALLOWED on Query File." significa que a aplicação está tentando fazer um  update em um campo de um ALIAS aberto por uma QUERY, que não aceita  alteração via AdvPL. Uma Query no AdvPl é um result-set read only e forward-only.

Comment: Para maiores informações sobre como funciona o acesso a bases de dados no AdvPL, recomendo a leitura dos dois posts abaixo: 
[Drivers e RDDs no AdvPL](https://siga0984.wordpress.com/2015/10/24/acesso-a-dados-drivers-e-rdds-no-advpl/) E 
[Acesso a Dados - Alias e WorkArea no AdvPL](https://siga0984.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/acesso-a-dados-alias-e-workarea-no-advpl/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se isso te ajuda: 
 Ao contrário do que informou, o exemplo abaixo não utiliza uma clausula de sql explícita:

Informo um índice: `dbSetOrder(1)` 
Passo as informações para o índice: `dbSeek(xFilial("SA1") + "900001" + "01")`

```
dbSelectArea("SA1")
dbSetOrder(1) // A1_FILIAL + A1_COD + A1_LOJA
dbSeek(xFilial("SA1") + "900001" + "01")

IF FOUND() // Avalia o retorno da pesquisa realizada
          RECLOCK("SA1", .F.)

          SA1->A1_NOME := "MARCOS AURELIUS TERCEIRUS"
          SA1->A1_NREDUZ := "MARCOS AURELIUS"

          MSUNLOCK()     // Destrava o registro
ENDIF
```

Link [TDN](http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=24347041).

Comment: Tentei isso ai ja também mas nada da certo.

Comment: o problema eu acho que é porque eu faço uma query no banco para selecionar um registro por vez para preencher a tabela de itens a ser mostrada para o usuario. Portando ja existe um DbSelectArea() ativo. Uma outra duvida, esse dbSeek, o que de fato ele faz? que parametros são esses passados para ele? e o dbSetOrder o que ele faz? na documentação eu não consegui entender exatamente de uma forma genérica o que é feito

Comment: Sem querer abusar mas só para ver se eu entendi. O dbSetOrder é tipo um indice para as colunas do banco? se eu tiver 4 colunas, sendo elas respectivamente A, B, C, D. e eu usar o dbSetOrder(2) eu setarei o indice para a coluna B. Portanto o dbSeek() deverá conter os parâmetros do registro que desejo alterar a partir do índice B, no caso eu deveria fazer dbSeek(valor_de_b, valor_de_c, valor_de_D) para então selecionar o registro desejado? Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eu acho inacreditável que ainda se use até hoje um código desses que pode ser feito em 2 linhas. Esses códigos do Protheus são trágicos, por isso dá tanto problema.

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho esse conceito, sou estagiário numa empresa, comecei a trabalhar com totvs semana passada, to apanhando bastante... Voce poderia me explicar ou me dizer como tenho que setar os parametros para que meu código funcione? a Tabela que desejo atualizar é a D4. O campo criado chama USALDO e foi criado por mim mesmo. A filial que quero alterar é a filial 01, e para selecionar  o registro preciso definir os campos D4_OP e D4_COD

Comment: havia esquecido de marcar como resolvido, eu so precisava descobrir o conceito de indice mesmo e o codigo postado por voce funcionou. O indice eh a sequencia em que as colunas aparecem quando se faz uma pesquisa no banco a grosso modo.